# Number of solutions of that congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, congruences, square-numbers

We consider $L=\   \{x\in (\mathbb{Z}/2^3 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \ \vert \ x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^3}\}$. I want to determine $Card(L)$.

If the group was the cyclic the answer would be $Card(L)=\gcd(4,2)=2$ but it's not the case here because $(\mathbb{Z}/2^3 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ isn't cyclic.

Or if we consider that $2^3=8$ we can try to solve the congruence $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ testing every number from $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. But we have the isomorphism with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ so the four elements are : $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ but how can we proceed to conclude ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your isomorphism does not exist! See the *Fundamental theorem of abelian groups*. Indeed, the solutions are $1,3,5,7$.

Comment: @bernard If $r\ge 2$ we have $Z/2^rZ \cong Z/2Z \times Z/2^{r-2}Z$ and this group is not cyclic if $r>2$. Here $r=3$.

Comment: This is false, by uniqueness of the invariant factors. Furthermore, the two groups do not even have the same order

Comment: @Bernard It's false indeed I would have written $(Z/2^rZ)^{\times}$ and the isomorphism would have been correct

Comment: For the group of units, I agree.

Comment: @Bernard Ok and the set $L$ contains the set of $x\in (Z/2^3Z)^{\times}$ such that $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {2^3}$. How can we be sure that $3$ is in $L$ ? I know that $(Z/2^3Z)^{\times}$ is order $4$ but the elements aren't ${1,3,5,7}$

Comment: Why aren't they the elements of $(\mathbf Z/2^3\mathbf Z)^\times$?

Comment: @Bernard Maybe I'm wrong but if $(Z/2^3Z)^{\times}=\{1,3,5,7\}$ that would mean that the group is cyclic ? The solutions $\{1,3,5,5\}$ would be true if it was $Z/8Z$

Comment: It can't be cyclic since all elements have order $1$ or $2$. Units are elements coprime to $8$, and less than $8$!

Comment: @Bernard Ok I agree with this definition. And if we decide to work with the isomorphism $Z/2Z \times Z/2Z$ we will have $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ and what will we obtain ?